# What is the syntax when giving data to an option of a terminal program?

Tags: shell, terminal

wkhtmltopdf tool convert html document to pdfs. But I want to specify the left margin. What should the syntax be?

```
$ wkhtmltopdf --margin-left=10 ex1.html ex1.pdf
Unknown long argument --margin-left=10
```

Answer (score 1):

Every terminal program may vary in its syntax a bit. Try

```
wkhtmltopdf --help
```

To see if there's a commands list.

Also found a manual https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt when searched for it. Suggests that the syntax is:

```
wkhtmltopdf --margin-left 10mm
```

Answer (score 0):

All I needed was to give 1 space between the option and the value and 2 spaces for the next option

`wkhtmltopdf --margin-left 10  --margin-right 10 ex1.html ex1.pdf`